Launchpad is not opening
I have a prod cm on link https://somenumber-cm.azurewebsites.net/sitecore
I am directed to
https://somenumber-cm.azurewebsites.net/identity/externallogincallback?ReturnUrl=%2fsitecore%2fclient%2fApplications%2fLaunchpad%3fsc_lang%3den&sc_site=shell&authenticationSource=Default
This is where the launchpad shall be opened, this is Sitecore 10 also https://somenumber-cm.azurewebsites.net/sitecore/shell/sitecore.version.xml and sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx is working and showing data
This is hosted in azure.
and this screen is blank and page source also looks to be blank
sometimes below error is thrown
Error: Unsuccessful login with external provider.


did you check if you have javascript errors on console ? did you try on other browser or in incognito more ?

Is the url /sitecore/shell/sitecore/client/applications/launchpad? Does Sitecore desktop work for you /sitecore/shell/?

Did you checked the event viewer logs? Anything in that..

Did you check if any Firewall and Networking is the issue?
